# Update $scope var from http.get

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Can someone please explain why $scope.shopLocation does not get changed to = special once the for loops have been ran. I need to access this var data further down in the controller and I can't access it inside the http.get

If anyone has any links to good explanations of scopes/vars etc I would be grateful.

```
.controller('MapCtrl', function($scope, $http) {    
    $scope.shopLocation = [];

    $http.get('/x/xx/xxx/advertsearch_json.php')
        .then(function(res) {
            $scope.jobs1 = res.data;

            var special = [];

            var categories = [];

            for ( var i=0; i < $scope.jobs1.length; i++ )
                categories[$scope.jobs1[i]['CHCO_LOCATION']] = $scope.jobs1[i];

            $scope.jobs1 = new Array();

            for ( var key in categories )
                special.push(categories[key]);

            $scope.shopLocation = special;
        });
    })
```

Comment: Can you add a link to a fiddle? You should be able to access `$scope.shopLocation` from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is that you aren't ensuring that the rest of the logic occurs only after the asynchronous operation is complete. What you need to do is `return` the information you need in the `then` function of your `http` call, and then use a reference to the promise in order to get that returned value. It works like this:

```
var myPromise = $http.get('whatever').then(function(resp) {
  // do what you need to do
  return something; // return the value you'll need later
});

// elsewhere

$scope.foo = function() {    
  myPromise.then(function(something) {
    // use the value you returned ^. the logic here will run when the value is definitely available.
  });
};
```

This way, if you call `$scope.foo`, your logic will definitely have the value from the async operation available to it. Contrast that with the following code:

```
$scope.something;

$http.get('whatever').then(function(resp) {
  $scope.something = //whatever
});

$scope.foo = function() {    
  console.log($scope.something); // no guarantee this will be set
};
```

Comment: Selected this answer as it was the one that put me on track regarding async and ordering of scripts

Answer (score 0):

I believe your async code is causing the update to happen outside of a digest cycle. As such, the value *is* being changed, but you don't see it reflected on screen.

In this case, you would need to apply the scope--so after `$scope.shopLocation = special;` add:

```
$scope.$apply();
```

Comment: I think you are right, however I use apply further down in the controller and this throws a digest error having this twice. I will need to look in to this

Comment: Well, IIRC, you can't call `$scope.$apply()` directly inside of the controller function because the execution of the controller is taking place during a digest. Within your `then` success function, however, it would be fine (and needed) as that won't run until after the controller is done.

Answer (score 0):

i think it has to do with the scope of special.  it get's destroyed after http.get is finished.  you are not actually copying the contents in your provided code.  you should do a deep copy.  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy

```
.controller('MapCtrl', function($scope, $http) {    
$scope.shopLocation = [];

$http.get('/x/xx/xxx/advertsearch_json.php')
    .then(function(res) {
        $scope.jobs1 = res.data;

        var special = [];

        var categories = [];

        for ( var i=0; i < $scope.jobs1.length; i++ )
            categories[$scope.jobs1[i]['CHCO_LOCATION']] = $scope.jobs1[i];

        $scope.jobs1 = new Array();

        for ( var key in categories )
            special.push(categories[key]);

        $scope.shopLocation = angular.copy(special);
    });
})
```

Comment: If something is still referencing a value in a scope which is closing, the value will remain available to it. This is where the term "closure" comes from.

Answer (score 0):

So this was as simple as just calling the later function that was using the new data inside the 'then'

```
    $http.get('/pb3/corporate/Apostrophe/advertsearch_json.php')
        .then(function(res) {
            $scope.jobs1 = res.data;

            var special = [];

            var categories = [];

            for ( var i=0; i < $scope.jobs1.length; i++ )
                    categories[$scope.jobs1[i]['CHCO_LOCATION']] = $scope.jobs1[i];
                    $scope.jobs1 = new Array();
            for ( var key in categories )
                    special.push(categories[key]);


            $scope.shopLocation = special;

            **createPoints();**

    });
```

Thanks to everyone for their help